Neptune Cardinality for mergeV option error
I am using gremlingo to write golang query to upsert value when match a vertice and replace this value with single cardinality so that it will not append value that is accepted as default of list in neptune, why are they doing list by default.
The following command runs into error
g.MergeV(map[interface{}]interface{}{ gremlingo.T.Label: "User", "email":           "abc@abc.com", }).Option(gremlingo.Merge.onMatch, map[interface{}]interface{}{"email": "abcd@abc.com",}, gremlingo.Cardinality.Single).Id().Next() 
2024/05/05 07:16:56 Error occurred during operation gremlinServerWSProtocol.responseHandler(): 'E0502: error in read loop, error message '{code:87 message:{"code":"InternalFailureException","requestId":"361e50e3-3fe6-4cce-a29c-79b6c20523ca","detailedMessage":"Could not locate exact method given the supplied arguments: NeptuneGraphTraversal.option(Merge, LinkedHashMap, Cardinality)","message":"Could not locate exact method given the supplied arguments: NeptuneGraphTraversal.option(Merge, LinkedHashMap, Cardinality)"} attributes:map[]}'. statusCode: 87
This is what i learned from tinkerpop official doc https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.7.1/reference/#mergevertex-step
But golang gremlingo does not work, or I just did not use it properly

The pattern that you're attempting was only recently added in TinkerPop 3.7.0: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_map_and_cardinality
Amazon Neptune's latest engine version (1.3.1.0) currently only supports up to TinkerPop 3.6.5:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.3.1.0.html#engine-releases-1.3.1.0-query-versions
The TinkerPop link above also discusses a potential workaround using property() steps within the option() steps.
